# Find the relationship between angles in a right-angled triangle given relative lengths of hypothenous and perpendicular

Tags: trigonometry

Take a right angled triangle.

The angle $\angle A$ is the right angle.

What is the difference between $\angle B$ and $\angle C$ if the hypothenous is four times the lenght of the perpendicular drawn from $A$?

Comment: I think you need to clarify a little. A picture might help? All the angles in the interior will be acute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $D$ the food point of the perpendicular to $c$ then we get $AD=h_c\cot(\alpha)$ and $DB=h_c\cot(\beta)$ adding both equations we get $$c=h_c(\cot(\alpha)+\cot(\beta))$$ therefore $$4=\cot(\alpha)+\cot(\beta)$$ and with $$\beta=\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha$$ we get $$4=\cot(\alpha)+\tan(\alpha)$$ from here you will get $\alpha$ and then $\beta$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a rough diagram to get you started:

[image]

We know that the angles are related by

$z + w = 90$, $x + y = 90$, $w + x = 90$, $z + y = 90$

and the sides by

$b^2 + c^2 = (4a)^2$

$a^2 + p_1^2 = c^2$,

$a^2 + p_2^2 = b^2$ and

$p_1 + p_2 = 4a$.

We also have a large number of trigometric relations, e.g. $b = 4a \cos x$.

---

Now, given all that, what have you tried?

Comment: I applied angle difference formula for sin(x-y)=(sinx)(cosy)-(cosx)(siny) to find the value of the difference required in terms of sine

Comment: It is I think more efficient to find the tan of the difference.